# How can you active the Script Menu Bar with AppleScript?

Tags: applescript, script, menu-bar

In AppleScript if you want to show the `Script Menu` in the menu bar you have to:

1. Click Applications
2. Scroll down and click Utilities
3. Click Script Editor (this was called AppleScript Editor in older OS X
   versions)
4. Click the “Script Editor” menu item, then click “Preferences...”
5. On the Preferences dialog click “Show Script menu in menu bar”
6. If it isn’t selected, you’ll want to enable the “Show Computer scripts”
   option

but is there a file in system that I can target to activate this in a script?  Trying to build an installer that will turn this on when if not active but I'm having issues trying to find where in the system I can hit this.  Dont mind a `do shell` but prefer **not** to use Automator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### 10.13 (High Sierra) and before

If you do not want to have to go through **Script Editor > Preferences > General** to check the
 **[ ] Show Script menu in menu bar** check box, then here is one way of enabling the **Script Menu** using **AppleScript**:

```
tell application "System Events"
    if not (script menu enabled) then
        tell current application
            do shell script "open '/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/Script Menu.menu'"
        end tell
    end if
end tell
```

You could just use:

```
do shell script "open '/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/Script Menu.menu'"
```

However, since **System Events** has a `script menu enabled` *property*, it makes sense to check whether or not it's enabled first. Either way though, opening the *target file* loads the **Script Menu** and checks the **[√] Show Script menu in menu bar** check box in: **Script Editor > Preferences > General**

Also, from **Terminal**, you could just run:

```
open '/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/Script Menu.menu'
```

Opening the *target file* in any manner shown accomplishes the goal.

By the way, when the **Script Menu** is enabled the *target plist file* is:

```
com.apple.systemuiserver.plist
```

The *key* is a *Boolean* and is `NSStatusItem Visible com.apple.scriptmenu`, and will also have an *element* in the `menuExtras` *Array* as a `String` holding the *pathname* of the item.

Note that the information above was gathered under **macOS 10.13.5**.

---

### 10.14 (Mojave) and up

The script menu has been upgraded into a full-fledged application, instead of a `.menu` file. It is now located at `/System/Library/CoreServices/Script Menu.app`.

To activate it on 10.14+, the terminal/shell command changes to:

```
open '/System/Library/CoreServices/Script Menu.app'
```

Answer (score 0):

This preference is controlled by the plist at the following path: `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.scriptmenu.plist`.

Which contains the following (When off):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>ScriptMenuEnabled</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

The `false` is changed to `true` when it is activated.

You change this preference with a `defaults` command in `bash`.

```
defaults write com.apple.scriptmenu.plist ScriptMenuEnabled true
```

or

```
defaults write com.apple.scriptmenu.plist ScriptMenuEnabled false
```

**So in AppleScript:**

```
do shell script "defaults write com.apple.scriptmenu.plist ScriptMenuEnabled true"
```

or

```
do shell script "defaults write com.apple.scriptmenu.plist ScriptMenuEnabled false"
```

Comment: I see the file but the running in the terminal and `do shell` doesn't work on the fly.  Still searching for a solution without a reboot.

Comment: In **macOS 10.13.5** anyway, `ScriptMenuEnabled` is not a valid _key_ in the `com.apple.scriptmenu.plist` file. From what I see there are only two valid _keys_ for the `com.apple.scriptmenu.plist` file, `PutAppScriptsFirst` and `ShowLibraryScripts`.

Comment: @user3439894 I tested on Mojave but I suspect it would be same for all versions.

Answer (score 0):

I’m not quite sure about earlier versions of macOS but with macOS Big Sur, the application "AppleScript Utility" (which is located here… "/System/Library/CoreServices/AppleScript Utility.app/“) is scriptable.

With this, there is no need to have to open Script Editor.app’s preferences or edit any plist files.  There is also no need to reboot.

```
tell application "AppleScript Utility"
    set Script menu enabled to true -- true or false
    set application scripts position to top -- top or bottom
    set show Computer scripts to false -- true or false
end tell
```